# Angular: get access to projected FormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, projection

I want to create a base form component, that will have additional control over all other forms.

For example, I want to check whether the form is dirty, when user wants to close the form, or not.

Here is my base component form sample:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-modal-form',
  templateUrl: './modal-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-form.component.scss']
})
export class ModalFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(FormGroup, { static: false }) usersForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.usersForm);
  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.usersForm);
  }
}
```

And here is usage example:

```
<my-modal-form>
  <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
  </form>
</my-modal-form>
```

So both `console.log` calls gives me `undefined`. Here I want to get access to `FormGroup` instance so I can check is it dirty or not.

The question is - how to correctly get access to projected form (FormGroup)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ControlContainer` instead seems to work*:

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-content-child-get-value)

```
import { Component, ContentChild, OnInit, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-form',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class ModalFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(ControlContainer, { static: true }) formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.formGroup.value); // null
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.formGroup.value); // {firstName: "", lastName: ""}
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
  }
}
```

*caveat - I've not tried this approach so cannot assess it's viability. Perhaps OP can comment / answer post down line if viable?

Comment: I used this approach in my project and I can confirm it works in my case. Angular 8.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `usersForm` anywhere that is why you get defined.
When I check your template, you have `profileForm` instead of `usersForm`.

You should correct this `<form [formGroup]="usersForm">` instead of `<form [formGroup]="profileForm">`

Comment: It's querying by type not name though.